# Give me error while install polymer

Tags: npm, polymer

E:>npm install -g polymer-cli

npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1:   Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read babeljs.io/env to update!

npm WARN deprecated bower@1.8.2: ...psst! Your project can stop working at any moment because its dependencies can change. Prevent this by migrating to Yarn: https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '..."ordered-read-streams'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-12-23T05_41_50_907Z-debug.log

Comment: could you post the whole error message

Comment: install Yarn first....